# Activity created twice when called setRequestedOrientation() to display in Landscape mode

Tags: android

I have an app for Android, I want to force tablet (sw600dp and higher) to display in Landscape mode and phone to display in Portrait mode, so I handle in onCreate of my BaseActivity class

```
boolean isTablet= getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (isTablet) {
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else { 
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

And the way I put "isTablet" in bools.xml file and put it in

**values** folder for phone

```
   <resources>
        <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
   </resources>
```

**values-sw600dp** for tablet

```
   <resources>
        <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
   </resources>
```

And in AndroidManifest I use

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

just ensure to disable device orientation's sensor.

It seems to be my approach works fine (Landscape for tablet and Portrait for phone) BUT the problem happens when I run my app on Nexus 7 - **my activities create twice**. These steps are:

1. Hole Nexus 7 in Portrait (it's fine if I hold tablet in Landscape)
2. Then run the app

I find that the problem is the method setRequestedOrientation() (with 2 steps above). So I don't want to call that method anymore. I try to set orientation in AndroidManifest like:

```
android:screenOrientation="@integer/orientation"
```

Because:
SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 0
SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 1

I declare "orientation" in integers.xml file and put it in

**values** folder for phone

```
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">1</integer>
</resources>
```

**values-sw600dp** for tablet

```
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">0</integer>
</resources>
```

Again, my approach tends to works fine BUT I find that AndroidMenifest just understands "orientation" in **values** folder, not in **values-sw600dp** folder. I don't want my activities to call 2 times. Did you have a problem like that?? Could you solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Quote from lint : Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) 
Had the same problem, seems we have to use dynamic orientation changes, but it causes activity restarts.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [setRequestedOrientation(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)):

> If the activity is currently in the foreground or otherwise impacting
>   the screen orientation, the screen will immediately be changed
>   (**possibly causing the activity to be restarted**)

It's not being re-created, it's just being restarted to account for the change of orientation.

So just move the functionality that shouldn't be run twice to `onCreate` and you're done.

Comment: "possibly causing the activity to be restarted" As you said that the system didn't call onCreate(), But I wrote a Log in onCreate() method and it printed 2 times.

Comment: @Peter which Nexus 7 are you using 2012?

Comment: I'm using Nexus 7 2013 (Android 4.4) and another device Samsung 7 inch as well, both devices had the same problem.

Comment: @Peter tried with nexus 7 2013. Your described behaviour wasn't present.

Comment: you means you used Nexus 7 to test the problems and you didn't see it right? It's so strange, I tried many times and the problems is still there, by the way thanks for your helping. I'll create a simple demo to test that problem again.

Comment: Hey, I have followed the EXACT implementation you described, and I face the same issue. To be more clear: I have used a Nexus 7 2013 and a Moto G 4g, and observed the following: in Nexus 7, I have enabled auto-rotation from the device Settings, and even when I start my app when the device is in Portrait mode, the screen is switched to landscape and the activity is NOT restarted twice. However, in my Moto G, I have disabled auto-rotation from the device Settings (hence always in portrait mode), and when I start the app, the screen switches to landscape, however the activity DOES start twice!

Comment: Same problem here, has a solution been found yet ?

Comment: @RenaudFavier I stopped finding the solution, instead tried to live with it. It's a rare and special case which is device issue properly, so depends on your app, you can try to handle when the activity get restarted, read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent), it might help.

Comment: @Peter same here, I found a way to live with it, but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Simas answer is sort of correct, let me explain.

Let's say you are holding your device in a portrait position, you then start your `Activity` and in `onCreate` you call the following:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Then, you are basically telling the device it should rotate (since you are holding the device in portrait mode).

But if you hold the device in landscape before launching your `Activity` and call the same as above, your device doesn't need to rotate since it is already in landscape mode.

As we all know, rotating your device causes the `Activity` to be destroyed and created again. The same goes for when calling `setRequestedOrientation` (if the device is currently not in the requested position).

---

So.. How to deal with it.

- The first and most obvious option would be to not call
  `setRequestedOrientation`. Instead handle your rotation by using
  `onSaveInstanceState` to store your values and
  `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore the values that were stored in
  bundle, etc..
- In my case, because of the design of my application, I had to use
  `setRequestedOrientation` because I'm rotating the device based on the
  selected video dimensions.

  Here is how I accomplished this.

  Since I want to handle rotation myself, I first had to add the
  following in my manifest:

  ```
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
  ```

  By doing this you are overriding [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes). As
  mentioned in the docs - `This technique should be considered a last
  resort`

  Next, I created a different layout for when I want to rotate the
  device to landscape and called the following:

  ```
  private void rotateScreen(Uri vidUri) {
      try {
          MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
          Bitmap bmp;
          retriever.setDataSource(this, vidUri);
          bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();

          videoWidth = bmp.getWidth();
          videoHeight = bmp.getHeight();

          if (videoWidth > videoHeight) {
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player_land);
              this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
          }
          if (videoWidth < videoHeight) {
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
              this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
          }

      } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
          Log.e("MediaMetadataRetriever", "- Failed to rotate the screen");

      }
  }
  ```

  Since everything in my portrait layout is in my landscape
  layout, I do not have to worry about resources not being found.

---

The solution I went with will not work for all applications (if you have different resources for different orientations) but in my case, I use all the same resource, resized and moved around to better fit the landscape view.

Answer (score 0):

In my case My screen orientation in manifest was portrait. I have changed it to landscape

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

then remove the line

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

from the onCreate block
This solved my problem. Sometimes the answer might be that easy